# Scrapy read list of URLs from file to scrape?

Tags: python, scrapy

I've just installed scrapy and followed their simple dmoz [tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) which works. I just looked up basic file handling for python and tried to get the crawler to read a list of URL's from a file but got some errors. This is probably wrong but I gave it a shot. Would someone please show me an example of reading a list of URL's into scrapy? Thanks in advance.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    f = open("urls.txt")
    start_urls = f

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You were pretty close.

```
f = open("urls.txt")
start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
f.close()
```

...better still would be to use the context manager to ensure the file's closed as expected:

```
with open("urls.txt", "rt") as f:
    start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
```

Comment: `readlines()` retains the newlines at the end of each line. I've submitted an edit that will `strip()` the newlines and close the file.

Answer (score 8):

If Dmoz expects just filenames in the list, you have to call strip on each line.  Otherwise you get a '\n' at the end of each URL.

```
class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [l.strip() for l in open('urls.txt').readlines()]
```

Example in Python 2.7

```
>>> open('urls.txt').readlines()
['http://site.org\n', 'http://example.org\n', 'http://example.com/page\n']
>>> [l.strip() for l in open('urls.txt').readlines()]
['http://site.org', 'http://example.org', 'http://example.com/page']
```

Comment: Thanks, when I ran the code from Brians example above I saw the errors about the URL formatting. The scrapy dmoz example had the URL's hard coded, and in quotes with commas. Removing the quotes and commas resolved the problem, and they are being read one per line now.

Answer (score 1):

Arise with similar question when writing my Scrapy helloworld. Beside reading urls from a file, you might also need to input file name as an argument. This can be done by the [Spider argument](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments) mechanism.

My example:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):                                                
    name = 'my'                                                               
    def __init__(self, config_file = None, *args, **kwargs):                    
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)                       
        with open(config_file) as f:                                            
            self._config = json.load(f)                                         
        self._url_list = self._config['url_list']                             

    def start_requests(self):                                                   
        for url in self._url_list:                                              
            yield scrapy.Request(url = url, callback = self.parse)
```