# Scrapy CrawlSpider not scraping anything

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

this is my very first time attempting to scrape websites using `CrawlSpider`, and to my sadness my spider is not returning any results. I am also new with python so if I make any obvious mistakes, please be patient with me.

Below is my code:

```
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from scrapy.settings import default_settings 
from selenium import webdriver
from urlparse import urlparse
import csv    
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy import log

default_settings.DEPTH_LIMIT = 3

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    def __init__(self,url,ofile,csvWriter):
        self.url=url
        self.driver=webdriver.PhantomJS('/usr/local/bin/phantomjs')
        self.ofile=ofile
        self.csvWriter=csvWriter
        self.name = "jin"
        self.start_urls = [url]
        self.rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='parse_website', follow=True)]

    def parse_website(self,response):
        url=self.url
        driver=self.driver
        csvWriter=self.csvWriter
        ofile=self.ofile
        self.log('A response from %s just arrived!' % response.url)
        driver.get(url)
        htmlSiteUrl = self.get_site_url(driver)
        htmlImagesList=self.get_html_images_list(driver,url)

    def get_site_url(self,driver):
        url = driver.current_url
        return url

    def get_html_images_list(self,driver,url):
        listOfimages = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img') 
        return listOfimages
        driver.close()

with open('/Users/hyunjincho/Desktop/BCorp_Websites.csv') as ifile:  
   website_batch= csv.reader(ifile, dialect=csv.excel_tab)  
   ofile=open('/Users/hyunjincho/Desktop/results.csv','wb')
   csvWriter = csv.writer(ofile,delimiter=' ')
   for website in website_batch: 
      url = ''.join(website)         
      aSpider=MySpider(url,ofile,csvWriter)
   ofile.close()
```

Why is my spider not scraping anything? have I done something wrong in my code? can someone help me out?

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile, because you refer to `MySpider` before it has been defined (in case this is your actual indentation).

Comment: sorry my bad - my indentation in my actual code isn't wrong, I fixed the indentation in my original post.

Comment: What happens when you try to run your spider?

Comment: nothing happens - no error message, nothing. But after getting nothing even though I spent 45 minutes waiting for the scraped results to be displayed on my .csv file, I would say that my code is wrong

Comment: I don't think my spider is crawling the website that I specified in my input .csv file

Comment: oh wait!something popped up on my screen. It says: `raise KeyError("Spider not found: %s" % spider_name) Key Error:'Spider not found: jin'` how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're not supposed to be launching the spider this way, see how it's done in the excellent [scrapy tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)

`scrapy crawl jin`

also, if you wish to read url/s from an external file see [Scrapy read list of URLs from file to scrape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376630/scrapy-read-list-of-urls-from-file-to-scrape)

last, output is done by creating [items](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html) and handle them using configured [pipelines](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) if you wish to write them to a csv file use [csv item exporter](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#csvitemexporter)