# Python crawl multiples URLs from a CSV and export to another CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scrapy

I need to loop over URLs stored in a CSV file. I want to extract phones and ZIPs from the URLs listed.

Please if you can help me, I appreciate!

```
   # read csv with just url per line
    with open('urls.csv') as file:
        start_urls = [line.strip() for line in file]

    def start_request(self):
        request = Request(url = self.start_urls, callback=self.parse)
        yield request
    
    def parse(self, response):
    
            html = response.body
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
            text = soup.get_text()

            phone = re.findall(r'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}', html, re.MULTILINE)
            zipcode = re.findall(r'(?<=, [A-Z]{2} )\d{5}', html, re.MULTILINE)
            phn_1 = []
            zipcode_1 = []
´´´
```

Comment: Hi! Please take read on how to ask a question as to maximize your chances of getting help (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, post a [mcve] and try to minimize the focus of the question. Posting a huge chunk of code and saying "hey it doesnt work" makes it way harder for other devs to help you ;} What exactly is not working?

Comment: Sorry :(. I can´t crawl multiples websites from a csv list. I want to add with open (urls.cvs)...

Comment: Please create a minimal working example.

Comment: I already change my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrapy read list of URLs from file to scrape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376630/scrapy-read-list-of-urls-from-file-to-scrape)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In fact, I can loop but I can´t get the information that I need while I´m looping.

Answer (score 1):

You described your goal but didn't mention what part is currently not working.

You wrote this:

```
    def start_request(self):
        request = Request(url=self.start_urls, callback=self.parse)
        yield request
```

It isn't obvious that that's what you want.
In particular I would expect Request() to accept
a single url rather than a list.
Also, using a callback is fine but perhaps fancier than needed.
Try this simplified approach:

```
for url in start_urls:
    self.parse(Request(url=url))
```

---

I'm sure this expression works fine for you:
`[line.strip() for line in file]`.
To emphasize that it is all about dealing with newlines,
it would be clearer to use

```
line.rstrip()
```

instead of

```
line.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer! I can looping but I'm not able of getting the phones and ZIPs while I´m looping for get after an CSV with the data.
Any help I would appreciate!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).